# Breeze.js/EF - ID for inserted record is needed for an update in the same SaveChanges batch

Tags: frameworks, entity, breeze, identity

Scenario:  User adds a new "contact" record (name, phone, email) nothing special there.  At the same time, he indicates this contact is the default contact, which is a FK column in the customer table.  When I SaveChanges I need to insert the new contact, and then update the customer record with the new contact ID from the insert.  I'm using EF,  Tables are using Identity for all key columns.

First question, can this even be done?
Secondly, if so, how?

thanks

Comment: Where do you set the flag? Do you send that flag to server or should the logic be completely on client?

Comment: The flag is set in the user interface on the client.  The user will add the contact information (name, email, etc) and on the screen there will be a checkbox so the user can indicate that this new contact will be the default contact for the customer account.  I can do the contact insert with no problem.  But then I need to update the customer account record, and I need the ID of the contact that was just inserted.  This contact ID will go in the column "DefaultContactID" on the customer record.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify SaveOptions and set a tag in there which you then read on server - depending on the value you either set to default or not.

Other option would be to set an `if` statement before saving, call your save and then place a promise to make another call to server to set that new instance as default.

Or you could load customer account (which might not be loaded, but somehow I think it should) and set default ID to the one of newly created customer and then just call SaveChanges which would send both customer account and newly created contact to server at the same time.

Those are three solutions. First one seems a bit of an overkill, 2nd one is okayish but I wouldn't use it in case promise didn't get back or something. Third solution is perfect if you already have your customer account loaded.

Comment: I will have the customer account loaded.  Your 2nd suggestion is the one I was going to do but was looking for a way to handle this on the server.  I can't send them to the server at the same time (option #3).  The key for the contact is an IDENTITY field and will be created by the db.  I have to wait for the insert to complete, and then **get the ID back** before I can issue the UPDATE on the customer record.   Your idea of using a promise in this scenario makes sense but now I have 2 separate transactions.  This is just a sample of multiple scenarios where this could occur.

Comment: @mwill You can set ID. If ID is autoset by database, breeze will set default ID as -1 or something like that. Breeze on server will recognize that and replace all keys and foreign keys set as -1 to newly assigned value by the database.